# Fixing the duality $L^\infty(X)= L^1(X)^*$ for Radon measure spaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, measure-theory, harmonic-analysis, duality

Consider the following fragment from Folland's book "A course in abstract harmonic analysis":

[image]

Let me denote the Borel subsets of $X$ by $\mathscr{B}(X)$. Folland claims that if $\mu$ is a Radon measure on a locally compact Hausdorff space, then the canonical map
$$L^\infty(X, \mu)\to L^1(X, \mathscr{B}(X), \mu)^*$$
(where $L^\infty(X, \mu)$ is "modified $L^\infty$") is surjective.

How exactly does this follow from decomposability of the Carathéodory extension of a Radon measure? Let us denote the Carathéodory extension by $\mu^*$. Then given $\omega \in L^1(X, \mu)^*$, since we can identify $L^1(X, \mu)= L^1(X, \mu^*)$ as Banach spaces, we can view $\omega \in L^1(X, \mu^*)^*$. By decomposability of $\mu^*$, we have $L^1(X, \mu^*)^*= L^\infty(X, \mu^*)$ and somehow I want to get to a function in $L^\infty(X, \mu)$.

I am beginning to suspect this claim is false. Everywhere I see this, or a similar claim, a text is referenced on which one works with a larger $\sigma$-algebra than the Borel subsets.

Comment: But notice that Folland gives a _new_ definition of $L^\infty$ is.  That's the whole point (as I see it) of this definition of "locally Borel" and so forth.  I think if you then look at a source (e.g. Cohn) that tells you about $\mu^*$ and $\mu^*$-measurable sets, you find a close link with locally Borel sets.

Comment: @MatthewDaws Yes my question is about the new $L^\infty$ space. Folland never mentions changing the underlying $\sigma$-algebras. I want to show that $L^\infty = (L^1)^*$ where $L^\infty$ is modified as in Folland.

Comment: "Folland never mentions changing the underlying $\sigma$-algebras."  Yes, he does!  The definition of "locally measurable"...

Comment: @MatthewDaws To clarify: do you agree that Folland claims that the canonical map $L_N^\infty(X)\to L^1(X, \mathcal{B}(X), \mu)^*$ where $L_N^\infty(X)$ is "modified $L^\infty(X)$" is an isometric isomorphism?

Comment: Yes, I agree.  However, if you also "modify" $L^1$ you get the same space (because the support of any $L^1$ function is $\sigma$-finite).

Comment: @MatthewDaws Still that does not quite solve my question. We get an isometric isomorphism $L^1(X, \mu^*) = L_N^\infty(X, \mu^*)$ where $\mu^*$ is the Carathéodory extension of $\mu$. We can also identify $L^1(X, \mu^*) = L^1(X, \mu)$ (by your last comment), so this gives $L^1(X, \mu)^* = L_N^\infty(X, \mu^*)$. But we need $L_N^\infty(X, \mu)$. This is what I meant with "the $\sigma$-algebra does not change". Somehow, it looks like we need to be able to identify $L_N^\infty(X, \mu)= L_N^\infty(X, \mu^*)$ which I am not sure is even possible.

Comment: The remaining gap is "$L_N^\infty(X, \mu)= L_N^\infty(X, \mu^*)$"?

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker I guess so. But I don't know if this is true.